# Geo Chart ready event listener not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have a loading dialog that I want to display while redrawing the chart with a new data table and dismiss it when finished. Based on the Google documentation the ready event is triggered after the map is drawn. However, when I add a ready even listener it is not being called. What is causing this and how can I accomplish what I'm trying to do.

```
chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
$(document).ready(function(){
    radioBtn = $(".geochart-radio");
    radioBtn.on('click',function (){
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart,'ready',function (){
            console.log("ready event triggered");
        });
        chart.draw(populationDt,options);
    });
});
```